# Ruby string to hash values

Tags: ruby, hash

I just started to learn Ruby!

I have the following string:

```
"Mark Smith, 29"
```

and I want to convert it to hash, so it looks like this:

```
{:name=>"Mark", :surname=>"Smith", :age=>29}
```

I've written the following code, to cut the input:

```
a1 = string.scan(/\w+|\d+/)
```

Now I have an array of strings. Is there an elegant way to convert this to hash? I know I can make three iterations like this:

```
pers = Hash.new
pers[:name] = a1[0]
pers[:surname] = a1[1]
pers[:age] = a1[2]
```

But maybe there is a way to do it using `.each` method or something like this? Or maybe it is possible to define a class Person, with predefined keys `(:name, :surname, :age)`, and then just "throw" my string to an instance of this class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do like,

```
%i(name surname age)
   .zip(string.scan(/\w+|\d+/))
   .to_h
# => {:name=>"Mark", :surname=>"Smith", :age=>"29"}
```

Or, you can take the benefit of [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Struct.html), like:

```
Person = Struct.new(:name, :surname, :age )
person = Person.new( *string.scan(/\w+|\d+/) )
person.age  # => "29"
person.name # => "Mark"
```

Comment: Thank you for help and showing me Struct and zip - I will read about these elements to fully understand them.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, precision and clarity I'd do it like so:

```
"Mark Smith, 29" =~ /(\w+)\s+(\w+),\s+(\d+)/
  #=> 0 
{ :name=> $1, :surname=> $2, :age=> $3.to_i }
  #=> {:name=>"Mark", :surname=>"Smith", :age=>29}
```

Unlike `/\w+|\d+/`, this regex requires `"Mark"` and `"Smith"` to be strings and `"29"` to be digits.